# Performance issue with search of large in memory collection

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

I wrote a query to find node in nodedata from transitiondata but it is taking quite a long time to come out of that loop since it has 4 million records.

What we have :
1. Transition data(Collection) which will have **from** and **to** node.
2. Node data(Collection) which will have key which is equals to **form** or **to** node from Transition data(Collection)

What is required out of these collections:
1. Collection which should have Transition Data(from, to) and the corresponding nodes from Node data(from key) and (to key)

The code what i wrote works fine, but it takes lot of time to execute. Below is the code.

```
foreach (var trans in transitions)
        {
            string transFrom = trans.From;
            string transTo = trans.To;

            var fromNodeData = nodeEntitydata.Where(x => x.Key == transFrom).FirstOrDefault();
            var toNodeData = nodeEntitydata.Where(x => x.Key == transTo).FirstOrDefault();

            if (fromNodeData != null && toNodeData != null)
            {
                //string fromSwimlane = fromNodeData.Group;
                //string toSwimlane = toNodeData.Group;
                string dicKey = fromNodeData.sokey + toNodeData.sokey;
                if (!dicTrans.ContainsKey(dicKey))
                {
                    soTransition.Add(new TransitionDataJsonObject
                    {
                        From = fromNodeData.sokey,
                        To = toNodeData.sokey,
                        FromPort = fromPortIds[0],
                        ToPort = toPortIds[0],
                        Description = "SOTransition",
                        IsManual = true
                    });
                    dicTrans.Add(dicKey, soTransition);
                }
            }
        }
```

That is the loop which takes time to execute. I know the problem is in that two Where clause. Because transitions will have 400k and nodeEntitydata will have 400k. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Note: A `Lakh` is a unit in the Indian number system. It is the equivalent of `100 000` in the decimal number system. så `40 Lakh` is `4 000 000`.

Comment: What kind of collection is `nodeEntityData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `nodeEntitydata` is just a normal collection.  The problem you're facing is that performing a `Where` on an in memory collection has linear performance, and you've got a lot of records to process.

What you need is a `Dictionary`.  This is much more efficient for searching large collections, because it uses a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) to do the search rather than a linear search.

If `nodeEntitydata` isn't already a `Dictionary`, you can create a Dictionary from it like this:

```
var nodeEntitydictionary = nodeEntitydata.ToDictionary(n => n.Key);
```

You can then consume the dictionary like this:

```
var fromNodeData = nodeEntitydictionary[transFrom];
var toNodeData = nodeEntitydictionary[transTo];
```

Creating the Dictionary will be fairly slow, so make sure you only do it once at the point where you populate `nodeEntitydata`.  If you have to keep re-instantiating the `Dictionary` too frequently then you won't see much of a performance benefit, so make sure you reuse it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use *direct access* to the dictionary entry:

```
var fromNodeData = nodeEntitydata[transFrom];
var toNodeData = nodeEntitydata[transTo];
```